# how to use for loop to create right angled triangle?

Tags: python

```
I want to print :
    1
   12
  123
 1234
```

and i have tried:

```
num=int(input("number"))
space=int(num)
count=1
while count<num:
  if count==1:
    print(" "*space,count)
    count=count+1
    space=space-1
    while count>=2:
      for n in range(2,num):
        print(" "*space,list(range(1,n))
        space=space-1
```

But it doesn't work.
How can i print the designated result ?
Thanks

Comment: Please put the code in the post, not an image of it.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code so it is an exact representation of the code you have in your editor.

Comment: I have just uploaded the code.

Comment: Great. Now please explain what "doesn't work" mean. What is it doing that does not meet your expected behaviour.

Comment: @idjaw looking at that code, "what does work" should be the proper question..

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `num=int(input("number: "))+1;print('\n'.join('{:>{}}'.format(''.join(str(u)for u in range(1,i)),num)for i in range(2,num+1)))` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring There's no way they can even read that code, much less reproduce it.  This is a case that calls for baby steps

Answer (score 0):

```
print(" "*space,list(range(1,n))
```

Count the parentheses on this line.  One of them isn't closed, which it has to be to work as you intend.

Also note that your `while` loop will never stop running.

As a general rule of thumb, whenever you know exactly how many times you should do something, you should use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop

Let's try to rewrite you code using a `for` loop:

```
num=int(input("number"))
output = ""
for n in range(1,num+1):
    output = ''.join([output, str(n)])
    space = ' ' * (num - len(output))
    print(space, output, sep='')
```

The only real substantive change I made other than a `for` loop is treating the output as a string rather than a list of numbers.

Comment: Can the shape be improved? Thanks !

Comment: @triumpyhyale In what way?  If it looks weird when outputted, it may be the font you're using to display the output